# Wordpress: how to get first level of children from a category?

Tags: wordpress, function, categories

I want to know if has a function that return only the first level of subcategories children.

```
Cat 1
   Sub-1.1
   Sub-1.2
       Sub-1.2.1
Cat 2
   Sub-2.1
```

Here I want only: Sub-1.1, Sub-1.2 and Sub-2.1

Cause using get_categories with child_of parameter brings me all children until the last node:

```
get_categories('orderby=id&show_count=0&title_li=&use_desc_for_title=1&child_of='.$this_category->cat_ID);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Please try

```
wp_list_categories(array('depth' => 2));
```

Comment: thanks, but this function was not customizable for my needs. So I found that get_categories('parent='.$id) returns only categories that are direct descendants =D