# Show Parent & 1st Level CHILD Category in a Drop Down List Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I currently have this code that shows all the parent categories in a drop down list.

**HTML/PHP Code**

```
<ul>
    <?php 
    $args = array(
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'hierarchical' => 1,
    'taxonomy' => 'category',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'parent' => 0,
    );
    $categories = get_categories($args);
    foreach($categories as $category) {
    echo '<li><a href="' . get_category_link($category->cat_ID) . '" title="' . $category->name . '">' . $category->name . '</a></li>';
    } 
    ?>
</ul>
```

There's no problem with the code below. Actually, it works perfectly! You can see it here at my wordpress website: [www.bendaggers.com](http://www.bendaggers.com)

What I want to achieve now is how can I add the 1st level child of the parent just what it shown in Image 1 below with the same effect.

**Image 1 - Sample**

This is what I want to achieve, whenever the user hovers on the listed Parent Category, it will display its 1st level child category as show in the image below.

[image]

**Image 2 - Sample Parent/Category Hierarchy.**

[image]

By the way, I need a working code PHP, HTML and CSS also.

I really appreciate you help and efforts, thank you very much!

Some additional Information that might be useful.

- The website is a wordpress website.
- All post are properly categorize (parents, 1st level child category
  is properly categorized).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wordpress: how to get first level of children from a category?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410695/wordpress-how-to-get-first-level-of-children-from-a-category) (The answer there uses `wp_list_categories`, which will already generate an HTML list structure out of the results – but that’s what you want to generate anyway, right?)

Comment: Thanks but your suggestion does not fit with my requirements. Thanks for looking that up.

Comment: Not sure if its appropriate to ask for complete working code for your project. Stack overflow is for asking specific technical questions, not to get free work completed.

Answer (score 2):

You can make function for check If the parent category has child category and pass parent term into newly created function. copy your ablove code and make a function and paste it in your custom function.

And get parent category(you should make first custom function to get paent term) and pass this term to your second custom function

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [wp_list_categories()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories) function.
Replace the entire code that you've provided here with this. `wp_list_categories(array('title_li' => ''));`
Add this to the stylesheet.

```
.cat-item {
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
}
.cat-item .children {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
.cat-item:hover > .children {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you refer wordpress function wp_nav_menu?

You can visit here for wordpress nav,

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu

And here is the guide for multiple level menus.

https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Menu_User_Guide